# MongoDB and Rails: How to create Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I was looking for a way in the initializer mongo_config.rb to create an index for locations. In other words, I want to be able to do

`db.map.ensureIndex({"gps" : "2d"})`

in the initializer and in ruby. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [MongoDB Ruby Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html). You want `ensure_index`, for example `map.ensure_index([["gps", Mongo::GEO2D]])` will do what you want, assuming `map` is a `Mongo::Collection`.

Comment: `ensure_index` is also available as a class method if you're using MongoMapper so `Map.ensure_index([["gps", Mongo::GEO2D]])` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Updated example: `map.indexes.create_one({some_key: 1}, {unique: true})` (also assuming `map` is a `Mongo::Collection`)